# Decoding Marathon electric motor model number

Tags: motor, three-phase

I have a 5HP 3-phase electric motor with the following model number / code:

`WVK 184T TDR 7026 DG`

It would be nice to decode this fully, but mainly I'm interested in its age to help judge its condition & the age of the equipment it powers.

Here's the full nameplate:

[image]

and motor:

[image]

Based on materials I can find so far it looks like the first 3 chars `WVK` *could* mean:

- W = 2021
- V = No thermal overload protection
- K = September

However it is presently 6 Sept 2021, so I doubt this date is correct! More likely this is an older motor predating the current date code scheme, which they apparently introduced in 1994.
I haven't been able to find any documentation or about any older codes.

References:

- https://www.regalbeloit.com/Brands/Marathon-Motors/Service-Support/Services/How-to-Read-a-Model-Number
- https://www.regalbeloit.com/brands/Marathon-Motors/Service-Support/Services/Motor-Date-Codes
- https://www.regalbeloit.com/-/media/Project-CMS/Regal/Images/Product/Brand/Marathon-Motors/datecode.pdf

Comment: W ... not 2021 but perhaps 1921 ?

Comment: @Antonio51 I should add a photo of the whole motor... I don't think it could be that old. It is a relatively modern construction AFAIK

Comment: @Antonio51 added one... not ideal but best pic I have on hand at the moment

Comment: I found while searching now FR-184T .... ok   :-)

Comment: Looks fairly modern, like 1980s onwards from the general style of the label. Its age won't tell you much about its condition, bearing wear , signs of corrosion, and insulation resistance will tell you more. I've seen (and use) much older motors that run perfectly well.

Answer (score 3):

Zip codes were introduced in 1963. The NEMA T frame series was "new" but well established by 1965. Efficiency marking is a good clue. I don't think that was done in the 1960's and may not have been done until the 1990's. The US energy policy act of 1992 was the first US regulation setting minimum motor efficiency.

In 1990, NEMA adopted a suggested standard for future design defining energy-efficient motors. That standard included "Table 12-6c Full-Load Nominal Efficiencies and Associated Minimum Efficiencies for Polyphase Induction Motors." The table specifies nominal 87.5% and minimum    86.5% for a 5 Hp, 4-pole, ODP motor.

Comment: Cool deductions. Since it seems like the current motor codes were introduced in 1994 that might narrow this down to the 92/93 timeframe.

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me like it was a design transfer with GE and the cat no H124(GE) refers to HG124.(obsolete)

https://www.regalbeloit.com/products/electric-motors/ac-motors-nema/general-purpose-motors/1-3-hp-general-purpose-motor-1-phase-3600-rpm-115-v-48-frame-tefc-5kh33fn85x

Does it matter how old it is? It's the bearing condition that matters 1st.

Answer (score 1):

As per this [code chart](https://www.regalrexnord.com/brands/marathon-motors/how-to-identify-age-of-marathon-motor) the first letter of the model number is the overload protection:
W = Protector UL recognized for Locked Rotor/Automatic reset protector* (plus motor recognition)

and the next two numbers are the manufacturing date code:

VK = Sept 1989